# I need login credentials fields for payment processors like amazon, google checkout etc

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a web app. i am using dotnetcharge control for payment processing. There are lots of payment processors supported,

I need login credentials fields for each processor.

Like for paypal transaction we need API Username, API Password & API Signature.

I want help finding these required fields for other payment processors like amazon, google checkout etc.

If anyone have done this pls share info.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The credentials should be entered on the site of the payment processor, never on your site. That is why not find then in your APIs.

Comment: I have to generate textboxes dynamically for each processors.Like for paypal transaction we need API Username, API Password & API Signature. So for paypal there will be three textboxes generated dynamically.

Comment: @incomplete: Peer is right. It would be an enormous breach of security if any payment processor would allow anybody to process user's passwords. They would loose all their credibility and no-one would be able to distinguish a scam site from a legitimate site anymore. You will not find any API that hands over their security out of free will.

Comment: You probably want to cache them to prefill when the customer comes back either. ....  However for security reasons the username and password should always be entered on the provider its webpage.

Comment: I need to know what fields you have to fill in order to proceed transaction for every payment gateway.Like in case of paypal transaction we need Username,Password & Signature.

Comment: I know the credentials should be entered on the site of the payment processor, never on my site. I want to know if anyone knows what are the fields e.g. for paypal username,password,signature..I need those fields to work on payment process for each processor.